# DynamicReports Geração de Gráficos Dinâmicos

Tags: mysql, swing

Olá, fiz alguns relatórios com o `DynamicReports`  http://www.dynamicreports.org/, ao procurar sobre como fazer gráficos encontrei vários exemplos, mas nenhum com os dados (mostrados no gráfico) sendo trazidos de um `Banco de Dados`.
Nos meus relatórios conforme a seleção na tela eu adiciono as colunas (conforme código abaixo):

```
 if (jRadioCodigo.isSelected() == true) {
            report.columns(Columns.column("Código", "id", DataTypes.integerType()));
        }
```

A minha `query` também é alterada conforme as  seleções na tela(conforme código abaixo):

```
 if (jComboBoxPessoa.getSelectedIndex() != 0) {
            queryNome = "and pes.nomePessoa= '" + jComboBoxPessoa.getSelectedItem().toString() + "'";
        }
```

`String query = "select pes.nomePessoa, pes.idPessoa from pessoa pes "`

`String queryFinal=query + queryNome`

A idéia é fazer o gráfico de forma semelhante no `DynamicReports`, ou até mesmo no `JasperReports` se é que é possível.
Alguém tem algum link, exemplo que possa ajudar?

Answer (score 0):

Consegui utilizando este exemplo do link, adaptando a minha necessidade.
http://www.dynamicreports.org/examples/databasedatasourcereport